# Password has " in the middle of the string

Tags: c#, passwords

I have a `string` that stores the password value.

**Example:** `Password` is `ABC"123`

I'm unable to store the password using double quotes as it is considering `ABC` as the password and the rest of the characters are causing an error.

How do I pass the complete password value in the string using double quotes?

Comment: Please, provide the *relevant code*. How do you store passwords?

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more context before anyone can answer this...

Comment: To pass quote in string you need to escape them like `"\"password\""`

Comment: Any correct password handling code **will not care** what the values are - it'll just encode (utf-8 or whatever) and hash (crypto) them. The fact that quotes matter suggests that you're doing two **very bad** things: 1) storing passwords in a database, and 2) not using SQL parameters. Put those two things together, and you're in a world of hurt. Please tell me I'm wrong about these guesses? If I'm wrong and you're actually just trying to hard code a literal with quotes: then `"that\"s fine"`

Comment: If you want to enquote the password, e.g. `abc -> "abc"; abc"123 -> "abc""123"` you can use `string enquoted = "\"" + Password.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";`

Comment: @MarcGravell wrote that way, it looks like storing password even hashed is wrong while it isn't

Answer (score 1):

I could go on and on about correct handling of passwords. I strongly suspect you're doing something here you really should not be, leaving a sensitive password in a place that will be trivial for anyone who really cares to read back. You may need to read up on constructs like `System.Security.SecureString`, encrypting sections of `.config` files, and similar.

But I'll put all that aside for the moment.

It's not clear to me what you're asking, but I *think* what this really comes down to is putting a double-quote (`"`) character in a C# string literal. There are **many** ways to do this, but probably the most common is escaping it with a backslash (`\`) character:

```
string foo = "\"bar\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the char \ to escape the char "

```
string str = "ABC\"123"
```